# PyCUDA how to get the number of used registers per thread when launching the kernels?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I have a kernel, how can I get the number of used registers per thread when launching the kernels? I mean in a PyCuda way.

A simple example will be:

```
__global__ 
void 
make_blobs(float* matrix, float2 *pts, int num_pts, float sigma, int rows, int cols) {
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (x < cols && y < rows) {
        int  idx = y*cols + x;
        float temp = 0.f;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_pts; i++) {
            float x_0 = pts[i].x;
            float y_0 = pts[i].y;
            temp += exp(-(pow(x - x_0, 2) + pow(y - y_0, 2)) / (2 * sigma*sigma));
        }
        matrix[idx] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to get the number without crashing the program if the real number used has exceeded the max?

The above is OK, it dose not exceed the max in my machine. I just want to get the number in a convenient way. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the question could be considered as a duplicate of another, or whether this could suit as an answer, but you can put the kernel into a `Kernel.cu` file, and then call `nvcc -cubin --resource-usage Kernel.cu`. It will show the register usage, `Used 19 registers,...` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Marco! Is this the only way? Previous i use the profiler, but it make my computer hang every time I start the session. So I am asking if there is any other way to do so. I think I will try what you suggested. Thank you!!!!

Comment: I don't know another way from the tip of my head. Profilers and other NVIDIA tools might provide the information as well, but the command line seemed to be the simplest here (particularly when the other tools imply a toolchain that has caveats in some cases). But there will likely be proper answers showing the alternatives soon.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the occupancy APIs have been exposed in PyCUDA. They would be the solution to your problem

Comment: I used the proposed method below to get 'num_regis', then use occupancy calculator to get occupancy. It may give me some hint. But there's something confusing me. I have one kernel using 54 regis / thread, it has a loop inside thread, when I increasing loop number, it crashes. So this time, I guess there is something different going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCuda already provides this as part of the Cuda function object. The property is called `pycuda.driver.Function.num_regs`.

Below is a small example that shows how to use it:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

kernel_src = """
__global__ void 
make_blobs(float* matrix, float2 *pts, int num_pts, float sigma, int rows, int cols) {
int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
if (x < cols && y < rows) {
    int  idx = y*cols + x;
    float temp = 0.f;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_pts; i++) {
        float x_0 = pts[i].x;
        float y_0 = pts[i].y;
        temp += exp(-(pow(x - x_0, 2) + pow(y - y_0, 2)) / (2 * sigma*sigma));
    }
    matrix[idx] = temp;
    }
}"""

compiledKernel = SourceModule(kernel_src)
make_blobs = compiledKernel.get_function("make_blobs")
print(make_blobs.num_regs)
```

Note that you don't need to use SourceModule. You can also load the module from e.g. a cubin file. More details can be found in the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.Function.num_regs).